# How to analyze every memory address used in my program?

Tags: performance, memory, operating-system

Experienced programmers know that memory access patterns matter. In particular, cache sets and page table locality access patterns.

So, is there a software that can take a look at all the addresses used in memory access in my executable[or assembly file] and give me a distribution on cache sets for both malloc-ed memory and register spills? Along with heat map for page accesses?

I'd prefer not do a hack and cook something up to do this. Isn't there a software that does this? Preferably something opensource and not one of the mega-expensive over-the-top performance tools out there.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you asked, but not only it will require a hack to track down page mappings, some memory management schemes do heap-randomization when allocating pages, for security reasons, pages are not allocated in a contiguous way. One more thing, recommending softwares on SO is off-topic and prone to question being closed.

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

Comment: @Tony: Yes, you misunderstood. The page map is irrelevant, only the pre-image of the map is relevant. That is to say the access on the Virtual Address Space at page size granularity[4KB or 2MB]; I want a heat map of that.